# Poll in Python aiogram

Tags: python, telegram, aiogram

I want to send a user a quiz-poll, using aiogram library and check if the user chose correct answer. How do I get this information? (whether the user checked the right answer)

I am not sure how to handle the polls, hope you will help.

Comment: `await bot.send_poll(chat_id=user_id,
                    question='Your answer?',
                    options=['A)', 'B)', 'C'],
                    type='quiz',
                    correct_option_id=1)`. So, my code is like this. How can I grab info which answer a user has chosen (is it correct)

Answer (score 1):

```
@dp.message_handler()
async def poll(message: types.Message):
    await message.answer_poll(question='Your answer?',
                              options=['A)', 'B)', 'C'],
                              type='quiz',
                              correct_option_id=1,
                              is_anonymous=False)
```

> **is_anonymous=False** - required parameter without it you couldn't handle answers

```
@dp.poll_answer_handler()
async def poll_answer(poll_answer: types.PollAnswer):
    # this handler starts after user choosed any answer 

    answer_ids = poll_answer.option_ids # list of answers     
    
    user_id = poll_answer.user.id
    poll_id = pollanswer.poll_id
```

You could save correct answer in some global variable, and equal it to the first element in list:
**answer_ids[0]**

**poll_answer** contains this attributes:

```
{
 "poll_id": "", 
 "user": {
          "id": , 
          "is_bot": , 
          "first_name": "", 
          "username": "", 
          "language_code": ""
         }, 
 "option_ids": []
}
```